# Decoding Git index file using C#

Tags: c#, git, low-level

Is there any documentation about internal structure of Git index file? From various book I know it's binary and it contains SHAs of staged files, I know about Git 'plumbing' commands helping to reveal index content...

But how about read index by myself using C#, for example?

I know that there several implementations of this feature, so it's possible to study the code:

- In Git itself;
- In libgit2 written on C;
- In GitSharp ported to C# from Java.

And all these options a bit complex, because need to hack around other's code. I would prefer to develop from scratch using data format explanation. If it's possible of cause.

Would appreciate your help very much!

Comment: Take a look at [LibGit2Sharp](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Take a look at `Documentation/technical/index-format.txt` in the `git.git` repository:

http://git.kernel.org/?p=git/git.git;a=blob;f=Documentation/technical/index-format.txt;hb=HEAD